# Angular 5 Main js bundle file too large and loading application takes 30 seconds

Tags: angular, optimization, webpack, deployment, angular-cli

I've tried and implimented many answers from stackoverflow and github issue discussion but I'm not able to reduce the main bundle file size. My package json file looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.2",
"@angular/common": "5.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.1",
"@angular/core": "5.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.1",
"@angular/http": "5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.1",
"@angular/router": "5.0.1",
"@angular/upgrade": "5.0.1",
"@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
"chart.js": "2.7.1",
"compression": "^1.7.2",
"core-js": "2.5.1",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
```

while the development dependency is:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "2.6.3",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
"@types/node": "8.0.50",
"codelyzer": "4.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
"karma": "1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
"protractor": "5.2.0",
"ts-node": "3.3.0",
"tslint": "5.8.0",
"typescript": "^2.4.2"
},
```

Using **ng build** I got bundled file of **6.2 mb** while using **ng build --prod** reduced bundled file size to **3.2 mb**. 
I also tried different flags like —build-optimizer with —vendor-chunk=false and --aot flag, though I think angular 5 includes all these by default but nothing changed and still the file is too large for production and it takes around 30 seconds to load the application.

Comment: check your asset folder may be large file is there

Comment: Just a Tip: To reduce Load time you can use lazzy loading in routes

Comment: you might did `import rxjs/Rx`, which eventually added to the bundle, use specific `imports`

Comment: @VeluDhanesh I only have some images in my assets folder and no other files.

Comment: @PardeepJain I'm looking to implement lazy loading in routes which may reduce 300-400 kb's but still I don't understand what is with 3.2mb bundled file!

Comment: @VIshalJain you can check that in developer console which file is taking too much size

Comment: @PankajParkar I've used on demand imports and haven't imported whole module anywhere.

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes I've checked that, it is the main bundled file which is generated by angular-cli when we use "ng build --prod" command.

Comment: any css and js files

Comment: @VeluDhanesh I've scss folder which is approx 150 KB in size and no additional js files, there are some plugins which I'm pulling off from node modules.

Comment: https://itnext.io/how-to-optimize-angular-applications-99bfab0f0b7c this blog might help you.